# AngularJS Add security and Local-storage Watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, local-storage, yeoman

I have a angularJS application which is using angular ui-router for routing.

I added the following level of security but that doesn't helped me out:

1. I am storing token and user role in local storage.
   on the basis of user roles i'm redirecting user to routes.
2. I have applied watch service on local storage but on refresh i 
   didn't get last(old) value of local storage so in this case my check(watch)  fails.
3. when someone changes token at local storage and refresh site.
   then i'm not able to check whether token is changed or not.
4. In this case user is able to view template but not able to fetch data cause i have added security layer at the backend. but i need to prevent access to template also.

Please help me add security at angular (client) to overcome these issues.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you are looking for a way to prevent the user from seeing the template if they do not have the required permissions. What i did is, when changing pages, first check to see if the user has the correct permission. In each state, i add the permission required to get to the page.

```
//these are the permissions the user currently has
var currentPermissions = {
  "User.Read":true,
  "User.Create":false
}


var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config( function($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('page1', {
        url: "/page1",
        data: {permission: "User.Read"}, //the perm required
        template: "Page 1"
    })    
    .state('page2', {
        url: "/page2",
        data: {permission: "User.Read"},
        template: "Page 2"
    })
    .state('page3', {
        url: "/page3",
        data: {permission: "User.Create"},
        template: "Page 3"
    })
    .state("noAccess", {
        url:"/noAccess",  

      template: "access denied"
    }); 
});


app.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 

           //check to make sure user has correct perm
           if(toState.data && !currentPermissions[toState.data.permission]){
                 event.preventDefault();
                 $state.go('noAccess');//redirect if user does not have perm
           }
        });     
});
```

Fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/Darin_Cardin/mwg33rm4/

Comment: i am doing same thing. but after login i am storing token(salt) at localstorage along with user roles eg. Admin/User and depending upon userroles i am allowing logged in user to view the pages(on $stateChangeStart). but if someone make change to localstorage(change User to Admin) and refresh page then he will able to see Admin Template in this case localstorage watch service doesn't work

Comment: By 'make a change', do you mean use something like a debugger? The client is by definition insecure, and unable to protect against this. I believe you would have to have something on the server that returns the page only if the user has the correct permissions. in the example above, you would use templateUrl instead of template, and have some permission check in front of it.

Comment: basically im storing token and roles in localstorage and i have applied watcher service on it. depending upon roles in localstorage im applying checks. watcher service works if someone makes changes in localstorage and using it(without refreshing). if someone refresh page after changing localstorage values then angular shows previous localstorage value as undefined in this watcher services doesn't work.. i need to overcome this issue.